# I can't select options in dropdown list in FireFox 48 using marionette driver and selenium 3

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I tried the new geckodriver with marionette turned on for FF48 and selenium 3 but the test can't select the option in the drop down list for any  element. My test works fine in FF45 and all other browsers. Only marionette driver does not select the option in the drop down list

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.Id("topic"))).selectByVisibleText(item);
```

The code works fine until I started using gecko driver with marionette.

Below is the code I am using to setup geckodriver with marionette.

```
       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",  System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\geckodriver.exe");

        ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();

        FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("DefaultProfile");
        myprofile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", ProxyType.AUTODETECT.ordinal());

        DesiredCapabilities dc=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        dc.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, myprofile);
        dc.setCapability("marionette", true);
        driver =  new FirefoxDriver(dc);
```

The test does not throw any exception when it tries to select an option from the  element.

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.Id("topic"))).selectByVisibleText(item);
```

After researching this issue, it turned out that FF48 has a bug and it is fixed in firefox ngithly 51. 
Is there any workaround to make it work in FF48 while I wait for the FF51 release?

Answer (score 3):

I am surprised nobody experienced this issue. I guess I might have posted the question in the wrong place because I did not get any response.
Anyway, this turned out to be a bug in Firefox 48. It is fixed in Firefox 51 (Nightly build).

If you are using Selenium 3 beta and Firefox 48 with geckodriver, you won't be able to interact with any drop down list using the webdriver. The issue was fixed in Firefox 51.

Comment: Firefox 51 will only be released in 2017.

Comment: I ran into this issue today when trying out the new marionette driver and firefox 48.  Glad I'm not the only one.

Comment: I am surprised not a lot of people are facing this issue. I am still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I did face the exact same issue, The work around which i did is the answer marked for this question.

[Selenium : Firefox Driver, Selecting an item from a dropdown using SelectElement in c# not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848542/selenium-firefox-driver-selecting-an-item-from-a-dropdown-using-selectelement)