# Not able to select element using SelectElement class in FireFox 48, Im using the latest drivers (marionette) using Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver

So the only automation I have ever done is what I kind of self learned at my current job using cucumber with ruby. I have had issues with my tests since upgrading selenium and gekko driver for Firefox 48+.
My CSS looks like the following:

```
<select id="scheduled-task-type" name="maintenance_task[task_type]">
<option value="16">Engine Runtime</option>
<option value="10">GPS Odometer</option>
<option value="13">Idle Time</option>
```

My previously working command was

```
@browser.select(id: "scheduled-task-type").select "GPS Odometer"
```

This no longer seems to function. It doesn't throw an error but it does not change the drop down either. It actually seems to think it correctly performed the action.

```
@browser.select(id: "scheduled-task-type").select "GPS Odometer"
=> "GPS Odometer"
```

I have tried to get it to click the drop down to open it (this works) but when I try to get it to make a selection after that using .click such as

```
@browser.select(id: "scheduled-task-type").click
@browser.select(id: "scheduled-task-type").option(text: "GPS Odometer").click
```

It still doesn't work and also doesn't throw an error.

Comment: I believe this is a bug in Firefox. Possibly fixed in Firefox 51 - http://stackoverflow.com/q/39026616/1200545 ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select an option using pure selenium in ruby, you can use following code snippet:

```
@browser.find_element(:css, "select#scheduled-task-type option[value=\"10\"]").click
```

@browser is your selenium webdriver instance and find_element is the method to find any element on a webpage. Hope this helps.