# Select element from dropdown by visible text using javascript executor

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, dropdown

I'm using selenium with Tor and I'd like to select an item from a dropdown list by the visible text or by part of text. The class Select doesn't work cause of a bug in firefox

So this is my code:

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("serverLogin"))); //Selects my dropdown
dropdown.selectByVisibleText(server);   //Selects the server
```

How can I do it using javascript executor?

Comment: Is "server" a value? If yes, it should be in double quotes.

Comment: server is a variabile string type.
public String server = "blablabla";

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: It doesn't select any element. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39046884/8142148 here is why

Comment: Did you check the 2nd comment in the link you provided?

Comment: Yes but I can't understand c#, I'm programming in Java

Answer (score 0):

Lets try with below code and see if it works-

```
WebElement dropDownListBox = driver.findElement(By.id("serverLogin"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){ if(select.options[i].text == arguments[1]){ select.options[i].selected = true; } }", dropDownListBox, "blablabla");
```

Comment: Still nothing... it opens the dropdown's options list but it doesn't select anyone then it closes the dropdown leaving always the first option selected

Comment: what is the firefox version you are using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Tor using the code I found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23320554/8142148 It works all perfectly except for dropdowns

Comment: can you paste DOM and some more of your exact code?

Comment: This is the output I get:
1504442314198 Marionette INFO startBrowser 613d1f95-3368-435e-87be-020aa90850fb
1504442314219 Marionette INFO sendAsync 613d1f95-3368-435e-87be-020aa90850fb
set 03, 2017 2:38:34 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFORMAZIONI: Detected dialect: W3C
Password Attuale: 1234aa
1504442315212 Marionette INFO sendAsync 613d1f95-3368-435e-87be-020aa90850fb
1504442345032 Marionette INFO sendAsync 613d1f95-3368-435e-87be-020aa90850fb
1504442345064 Marionette INFO sendAsync 613d1f95-3368-435e-87be-020aa90850fb

Note that it works on chrome

Answer (score 0):

I solved it creating a dropdown WebElement and sending to it the first letter to select my option, then sending Enter key.
Here is the code:

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("serverLogin")); 
        dropdown.sendKeys(server);  
        dropdown.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

thanks anyway.

Comment: actually does not work, even because you can't declare `Webelement dropdown` in javascript